# Raise Except errors

Tags: python

Hi in my assessment i need to raise value errors but my code doesnt work and i dont know why can someone help me please

my code need to ask uurloon and gewerkte_uren if the user doesnt enter int/float he needs to get a error and the program must end when when the program is entered correctly.

can someone please help me :(

```
def program():
    while True:
        try:
            uurloon = float(input("Hoeveel euro's verdien je per uur: "))
            gewerkte_uren = float(input("Hoeveel uur heb je gewerkt: "))
            salaris = (gewerkte_uren * uurloon)
            print(f"{gewerkte_uren} uren werken levert €{salaris} op.")
    except KeyboardInterrupt as a:
        print(a)
        raise
    except OverflowError as b:
        print(b)
        raise
    except ZeroDivisionError as c:
        print(c)
        raise
    except IOError as d:
        print(d)
        raise
    except IndexError as e:
        print(e)
        raise
    except NameError as f:
        print(f)
        raise
    except TypeError as g:
        print(g)
        raise
    except ValueError as h:
        print(h)
        raise

program()
```

new code:

```
while True:
    try:
            uurloon = float(input("Hoeveel euro's verdien je per uur: "))
            gewerkte_uren = float(input("Hoeveel uur heb je gewerkt: "))
            salaris = (gewerkte_uren * uurloon)
            print(f"{gewerkte_uren} uren werken levert €{salaris} op.")
            break
    except KeyboardInterrupt as a:
        print(a)
    except OverflowError as b:
        print(b)
    except ZeroDivisionError as c:
        print(c)
    except IOError as d:
        print(d)
    except IndexError as e:
        print(e)
    except NameError as f:
        print(f)
    except TypeError as g:
        print(g)
    except ValueError as h:
        print(h)
```

i almost got it but when you enter the first input correctly and second wrong it goes back to the first input how can i program it that if you do the second one wrong it asks you to insert the second one again instead of running the program again?

Comment: And what happens? What do you enter, what do you expect and what do you see instead?

Comment: Well what happens is if i try to run the program it immediatly goes to an error and it wont run normally but i think i got it now

Comment: look at my second code i edited it

Comment: So, you had indentation error. When asking a question, you should say which error is reported.

Comment: Oh, i didn't knew, next time i will do that!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `raise` if you want your program to continue the run. That's how you threw exceptions.

You can catch the exception when Python can't convert the vars `uurloon` and `gewerkte_uren` to Float

Like that:

```
try:
            uurloon = float(input("Hoeveel euro's verdien je per uur: "))
            gewerkte_uren = float(input("Hoeveel uur heb je gewerkt: "))
            salaris = (gewerkte_uren * uurloon)
            print(f"{gewerkte_uren} uren werken levert €{salaris} op.")
except ValueError:
        print("enter a number")
```

Comment: my assessment says ''
Do this by catching errors when converting text to numbers (string -> int / float).''

Comment: If the user enters letters or other characters instead of numbers, he / she should get a neat error message. Do this by catching (catch) errors that occur when converting text to numbers (string -> int / float).
Also make sure that the program does not end until the user has given correct input.

Comment: You don't need the raise, it will crash your program. But you need a `break` after the print in the try, to exit the loop. Try to run it and see what happened

Comment: i think i fixed it but i dont want to answer the question how can i comment without a question answer with my code so that you can look it up?

Comment: i think i know why the first one didnt work. my ''While True'' is in line with Except. but Except must be on the same line as ''Try''

Comment: you need only the `except ValueError` and not the rest